# I want to know if my use of fixed effects (PLM) is correct

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset (Young Lives Dataset) which follows children from age 8-22 in five different rounds. I am using information about the children's time-use in rounds 2-4, when they are still children, including hours they worked, chores, schooling, sleep, and time studying. Then in round 5 there is data on their earnings. I am trying to establish whether there is a relationship between hours worked and time spend domestic chores as children and their future earnings. I have other information that I have used as controls: wealth index (wi), household size (hhsize), cognitive test scores (ppvt_theta_mle and quant_theta_mle), and the main caretaker's level of education. I am choosing to omit one time-use variable (time spent studying) in order to obtain the effect of child work relative to that category. This was the output for the OLS regression without controls:

Call:

```
lm(formula = sum_result ~ domestic + market + hplay + hschool + 
    hsleep, data = ethiopia1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1544.0  -966.8  -440.5   380.3 29684.1 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  3501.23    1268.91   2.759  0.00589 **
domestic     -151.89      58.29  -2.606  0.00929 **
market        -83.42      53.75  -1.552  0.12098   
hplay        -124.90      59.28  -2.107  0.03537 * 
hschool       -78.22      69.86  -1.120  0.26309   
hsleep       -100.35      66.36  -1.512  0.13077   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1868 on 1056 degrees of freedom
  (2707 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.01333,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.008662 
F-statistic: 2.854 on 5 and 1056 DF,  p-value: 0.01441
```

This is the result of the OLS regression with controls: `Call:

```
lm(formula = sum_result ~ domestic + market + wi + hplay + hschool + 
    quant_theta_mle + ppvt_theta_mle + sex + hhsize + caredu + 
    hsleep, data = ethiopia1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2225.1  -897.2  -391.4   445.6 29113.1 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     4685.811   1791.982   2.615  0.00915 **
domestic        -260.603     83.913  -3.106  0.00199 **
market          -143.664     77.837  -1.846  0.06544 . 
wi              1304.878    508.162   2.568  0.01048 * 
hplay           -223.098     86.125  -2.590  0.00982 **
hschool         -196.677     93.597  -2.101  0.03604 * 
quant_theta_mle   22.609     43.377   0.521  0.60242   
ppvt_theta_mle    39.926     94.881   0.421  0.67406   
sex              237.935    169.681   1.402  0.16137   
hhsize            87.885     33.564   2.618  0.00906 **
caredu           -13.400      7.731  -1.733  0.08358 . 
hsleep          -224.861     92.442  -2.432  0.01529 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1741 on 592 degrees of freedom
  (3165 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.05595,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03841 
F-statistic:  3.19 on 11 and 592 DF,  p-value: 0.0003176
```

And finally, this is the output of the fixed effects regression:

`Call:

```
plm(formula = sum_result ~ hsleep + domestic + market + wi + 
    hschool + hplay + quant_theta_mle + ppvt_theta_mle + sex + 
    hhsize + caredu, data = ethiopia1, model = "within")

Unbalanced Panel: n = 373, T = 1-2, N = 604

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-15360.525    -41.017      0.000     41.017  15360.525 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
hsleep           -26.3093   151.5702 -0.1736   0.8624
domestic        -128.5119   122.4944 -1.0491   0.2953
market           -91.0580   124.6519 -0.7305   0.4659
wi               618.1638  1243.8891  0.4970   0.6197
hschool          -97.4061   148.4647 -0.6561   0.5124
hplay           -121.4124   129.1523 -0.9401   0.3482
quant_theta_mle    6.1397    79.5839  0.0771   0.9386
ppvt_theta_mle    39.9197   152.0135  0.2626   0.7931
hhsize            35.9455    88.4395  0.4064   0.6848
caredu             3.6820    44.6457  0.0825   0.9343

Total Sum of Squares:    505700000
Residual Sum of Squares: 500950000
R-Squared:      0.0094028
Adj. R-Squared: -1.7029
F-statistic: 0.209773 on 10 and 221 DF, p-value: 0.99529
```

I am trying to control for endogeneity. I know instrumental variables is probably a good way but I would like to try this first. If anyone also has suggestions on how to interpret these results it would be greatly appreciated.